# Azure EventHub : Unable to sample from an Event Hub

Tags: azure-stream-analytics, azure-eventhub

I'm unable to sample from a Streaming of an Event Hub entry:
The test query is :

```
SELECT
    *
INTO
    [OutputAlias]
FROM
    [gatewaytosqldatabase]
```

returns :

```
"An error occurred while reading the sample entry. Check that the input source is configured correctly and that the data is in the correct format."
in French :
 Une erreur s'est produite lors de la lecture de l'exemple d'entrée. Vérifiez que la source d'entrée est configurée correctement et que les données sont dans un format correct.
```

[image]

I'm able to receive datas from a coded python program. I've coded an EventHubConsumerClient with the help of the azure.eventhub.extensions package and all is fine, I can see my events sended to a specific consumer_group...

What is going on with the this tool ?
Looks like it reacts strangely.

Has anybody experience that before? How does the Query explorer of StreamAnalytics work for Event hub testing? Which consumer_group does it take? How to debug this message?

Thanks for any feedback on this.
Richard

Comment: Do you know what serialization format is used for the payload? JSON, CSV, AVRO? Note that you can always try the ASA extension in VS Code to sample data and test / write queries : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/quick-create-visual-studio-code

Comment: Hello Florian.Thankss for your feedback.

Comment: Payload is done via a iot plateform that pushes a message in a json format. with the help of the tool you mention I can see my asa job that's runninga and see in the input :     "Serialization": {
        "Type": "Json",
        "Encoding": "UTF8",
        "FieldDelimiter": null
    },

Comment: Solved by adding the correct Key of SharedAccessPolicy. Thanks to you Florien for helps me to solve by using the ASA extension in VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

Solved by adding the correct Key of SharedAccessPolicy. Thanks to you Florien for helps me to solve by using the ASA extension in VSCode.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).